# Java - WildcardFileFilter: Works on Mac, doesn't work on CentOs

Tags: java, regex

WildcardFileFilter works on Mac locally, doesn't work on CentOS.

1. Same exact code
2. File definitely exists in given folder:

> /path/file_170301.ZIP

Appreciate any help.

```
protected String getFileName() {
        String fileMask = MonthlyFileName(getProcessDate())
                .replaceAll("[0-9]{2}\\.ZIP", "*.ZIP");
        File dir = new File(context.getWorkdir() + "/");
        FileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter(fileMask);
        String fileName = (dir.listFiles(fileFilter).length == 1)
                ? dir.listFiles(fileFilter)[0].getName() : fileMask;
        return fileName;
    }
```

> can't open `/path/file_1703*.ZIP': No such file or directory

Comment: What's the output of `context.getWorkdir()`? Are you sure that folder contains *.zip files?

Comment: Yes, 100 percent

Comment: Which version of Apache Commons I/O are you using?

Comment: Manually open `/path/file170301.ZIP` in the same spot. Really, I don't think its even finding the correct working dir, because the file name should be a moot point.

Comment: 2.5 @LuiggiMendoza

Comment: @sln literally went to same directory to check the file

Comment: Then it looks like `dir.listFiles(fileFilter)` is having issues. You could try just `dir.listFiles("*")` without the length check to see what that returns.